# ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.math3.distribution.EnumeratedDistribution

Tags: java, maven, apache-commons-math

I'm using the apache-commons-math library to generate a number of items from an enumerated distributed list.
Upon writing the code I get no errors and the Netbeans code completion successfully suggests the imports needed for this code. There are no errors upon building the project as well.
But if I try to run the jar I get the following error on line 6 of the following code and I have no clue what to do.
I'm fairly new to maven so I might just be doing something wrong but I already tried to provide the scope instead of on compile.

The following code (line 6) throws the ClassNotFound error

```
private void initializeSSGUI() {
    final List<Pair<Spawner, Double>> itemWeights = new ArrayList<>();
    this.config.getSpawners().values().forEach((i) -> {
        itemWeights.add(new Pair(i, i.getWeight()));
    });
    Object[] spawners = new EnumeratedDistribution<>(itemWeights).sample(this.config.getAmountPicked());
}
```

Math3 imports

```
import org.apache.commons.math3.distribution.EnumeratedDistribution;
import org.apache.commons.math3.util.Pair;
```

The following code is the pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.typicalcraft</groupId>
    <artifactId>TCutilities</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-beta</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spigotmc-repo</id>
            <url>https://hub.spigotmc.org/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>jitpack.io</id>
            <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <directory>src/resources</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>plugin.yml</include>                    
                    <include>config.yml</include>               
                    <include>messages.yml</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spigotmc</groupId>
            <artifactId>spigot-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.1-R0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.MilkBowl</groupId>
            <artifactId>VaultAPI</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.PlayerNguyen</groupId>
            <artifactId>OptEco</artifactId>
            <version>1.15b</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-math3</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Error

```
[16:58:44 ERROR]: Error occurred while enabling TCutilities v1.0.0 (Is it up to date?)
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/math3/distribution/EnumeratedDistribution
        at com.typicalcraft.tcutilities.TCutilities.initializeSSGUI(TCutilities.java:119) ~[?:?]
        at com.typicalcraft.tcutilities.TCutilities.onEnable(TCutilities.java:54) ~[?:?]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.setEnabled(JavaPlugin.java:263) ~[patched_1.16.1.jar:git-Paper-34]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.enablePlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:380) ~[patched_1.16.1.jar:git-Paper-34]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.enablePlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:483) ~[patched_1.16.1.jar:git-Paper-34]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_16_R1.CraftServer.enablePlugin(CraftServer.java:498) ~[patched_1.16.1.jar:git-Paper-34]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_16_R1.CraftServer.enablePlugins(CraftServer.java:412) ~[patched_1.16.1.jar:git-Paper-34]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R1.MinecraftServer.loadWorld(MinecraftServer.java:471) ~[patched_1.16.1.jar:git-Paper-34]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R1.DedicatedServer.init(DedicatedServer.java:241) ~[patched_1.16.1.jar:git-Paper-34]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R1.MinecraftServer.v(MinecraftServer.java:940) ~[patched_1.16.1.jar:git-Paper-34]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R1.MinecraftServer.lambda$a$0(MinecraftServer.java:177) ~[patched_1.16.1.jar:git-Paper-34]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_241]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.math3.distribution.EnumeratedDistribution
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_241]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.findClass(PluginClassLoader.java:171) ~[patched_1.16.1.jar:git-Paper-34]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.findClass(PluginClassLoader.java:100) ~[patched_1.16.1.jar:git-Paper-34]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_241]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_241]
        ... 12 more
```

Comment: How are you starting the Java program?  What command line arguments are you providing?  Most importantly, what is the classpath the program is using?